# how to fix click button to show popup content and click out element area to close popup jquery

Tags: jquery

i have problem when trying setup code with Jquery

i want when click the button, the popup content will show, and when i click out area of content popup , the popup was close.

but my code have problems.
help me...

my code here :

```
<button class="popup_dangky"></button>

<!-- show popup -->
<div id="thim-popup-login" class="has-shortcode">
    content popup 
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
/*  jQuery(document).ready(function(){*/
        jQuery('button.popup_dangky').click(function() {
            jQuery("div.has-shortcode").addClass("active");
        });

        jQuery("html").click(function(e){
                jQuery(".has-shortcode").removeClass("active");
        });
/*  });*/
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify. What is your PROBLEM & what is the RESULT you are hoping for.

Comment: where is your problem ? not show , not hide , or ??

Comment: it's not popup form when click button .... 
below is right question. thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on `button`, `html`click event is also trigger at same time.
below is updated code.

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('button.popup_dangky').click(function() {
            jQuery("div.has-shortcode").addClass("active");
        });

       /* jQuery("html").click(function(e){
                jQuery(".has-shortcode").removeClass("active");
        });*/
        
        
        
        jQuery(document).mouseup(function (e)
          {
            var container = jQuery(".has-shortcode");

            if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
              && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
            {
              container.removeClass('active');
            }
 });
        
  });
```

```css
.has-shortcode{
  display:none
}
.active{
  display:inline !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="popup_dangky">click</button>

<!-- show popup -->
<div id="thim-popup-login" class="has-shortcode">
    content popup 
</div>
```